# Translator Bot using Google Translate API

Tags: ruby, google-api, sinatra, google-translation-api

Hey Stackoverflow Community,

I'm new to Ruby and working on a small project for a course assignment. I've to create a mobile bot that uses the Google Translate API and returns the translated text.

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to write the code for the bot to get the inputted text and output the translation.

Could anyone have a look, please? Would really appreciate it

```
def transl8 (input,lang)     #method to translate incoming text
  # Translates some text into Russian
  # Instantiates a client
 translate = Google::Cloud::Translate.new project: project-217401

  puts input + "Looks like you're speak in #{detection.language}"
  puts "Confidence: #{detection.confidence}"

translation = translate.translate input, to: lang 

 return "In #{lang} that's" + translation
end

def transl8 (input,lang)     #method to translate incoming text
detection = $translate.detect input
puts input + "Looks like you're speak in #{detection.language}"
puts "Confidence: #{detection.confidence}"
translation = $translate.translate input, to: lang
return "In #{lang} that's" + translation
end


def listlang #method to show language code
language_code = "en"
languages = $translate.languages
puts "Supported languages:"
languages.each do |language|
 puts "#{language.code} #{language.name}"
 end
end

configure :development do
require 'dotenv'
Dotenv.load
end

#Translate End-point 
https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2 endpoint

get "/incoming/sms/" do

"Hey! I'm AllSpeak, a translator bot. The list of supported languages are 
below. Just ask by typing (TEXT) (space) (Language Code)"

 incoming_text = params['Body']
 text_to_translate = incoming_text.split(' ')[0]
 lang_requested = incoming_text.split(' ')[1]
 twiml_body = transl8(text_to_translate, lang_requested)
  #return twiml here with twiml_body
 end

#Look into Including method to set default language for commonly used 
 phrases

puts listlang

transl8 (text)

# Build a twilio response object 
twiml = Twilio::TwiML::MessagingResponse.new do |r|
 r.message do |m|
  end 
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Translation API Code:

For `listlang`:

- You're missing an `end` on the `do` loop and you're not setting the project_id variable

For `transl8`:

- You're not initializing the `detection` variable

Sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require "google/cloud/translate"
$translate = Google::Cloud::Translate.new project: "slatebot-217401"

def transl8 (input,lang)     #method to translate incoming text
    detection = $translate.detect input
    puts input + "Looks like you're speak in #{detection.language}"
    puts "Confidence: #{detection.confidence}"
    translation = $translate.translate input, to: lang
    return "In #{lang} that's" + translation
end


def listlang #method to show language code
    language_code = "en"
    languages = $translate.languages
    puts "Supported languages:"
    languages.each do |language|
            puts "#{language.code} #{language.name}"
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm confused as to how to write an end-point that takes in the inputs from the user.
Note: We have to use Twilio - it's basically an SMS bot

Answer (score 0):

Jarod from Twilio. I noticed your question and wanted to suggest you parse the users SMS that would be incoming to your "incoming/sms". Once you have configured your phone number to make a GET request to "incoming/sms" Twilio will start sending incoming SMS to that URL. When Twilio does this it will also pass you a bunch of information in the http request. The incoming SMS body is passed as the `Body` in the request. So you could do something like this

```
get '/incoming/sms' do
  incoming_text = params['Body']
  text_to_translate = incoming_text.split(' ')[0]
  lang_requested = incoming_text.split(' ')[1]
  twiml_body = transl8(text_to_translate, lang_requested)
  #return twiml here with twiml_body
end
```

Does that make sense? Looks like your twiml method is mostly ready to go so just insert that at the end of your response and you should be good to go! Fun app. Excited to see it finished!

Comment: Thanks Jarod. This is the part I get confused with - how does Ruby know that the incoming sms is the same as 'Body'. It's not explicitly defined. Or is Body a default variable?